# Python & Couchbase Lock/Unlock mechanism

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, locking, couchbase

I'm running Couchbase 3.0 with the couchbase==2.0.7 library.

Is there a way to keep the document locked after you do the upsert?

```
rv = self.cb.lock("locked_key", ttl=5) # <-- document is locked
new_value = rv.value.upper()
cb.upsert("locked_key", new_value, rv.cas) # <-- document is unlocked
```

My problem is that I have more than one upsert on a locked document and if there are two threads that started executing the code in the same time, when thread1 does the first upsert the document is unlocked and thread2 aquires the lock, but the thread1 is not finished and at the next upsert an error will be raised.

Comment: In addition to my answer, it may be useful if you ask as a question separately what you're trying to do.  I don't currently see a situation where you'd lock, modify (without unlocking) and then modify again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the Couchbase lock is automatically released on a CAS mutation.  There is no behavior for modifying it and keeping it locked currently.